# Appropriate Architecture for Akka WebSockets with Cluster Sharding

Tags: java, websocket, akka, akka-http, akka-cluster

I am attempting to implement a way for users to connect to a specific websocket, which enables all connected clients to send and receive messages to all connected users.  This can be thought of as a group chat where there is a dedicated websocket URL per chat room.

I have used a handleWebSocketMessages route and used the following boiler plate code (source) for data distribution across connected users:

```
  Pair<Sink<Message, NotUsed>, Source<Message, NotUsed>> sinkSourcePair =
  MergeHub.of(Message.class)
      .toMat(BroadcastHub.of(Message.class), Keep.both())
      .run(actorSystem);

  Sink<Message, NotUsed> hubSink = sinkSourcePair.first();
  Source<Message, NotUsed> hubSource = sinkSourcePair.second();
  Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> broadcastFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(hubSink, hubSource);
```

When a message arrives via the websocket, I want it to be registered by the cluster sharded Actor (entity), which I complete using EntityRef.ask.

```
Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> incomingMessageFlow = Flow.of(Message.class)
Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> recordMessageFlow = ...
Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> broadcastFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(hubSink, hubSource);

return handleWebSocketMessages(incomingMessageFlow.via(recordMessageFlow).via(broadcastFlow);
```

The above works fine for clients connected to a single websocket but I want my websockets to be associated with a sharded Actor based on the websocket URL (e.g. ws://localhost/my-group-chat/ws).

Where should I define my broadcast flow? I've tried several approaches:

1. to define it within Route for websocket handling (makes no sense as it is created new for every connection)
2. to include it in a sharded actor (fails because of serialization requirements between sharded actors)
3. to store a map of broadcast flows so that when it exists for a specific URL it is utilized and when it doesn't exist it is initialized. <- this one worked but I don't like it

I believe the broadcast flow should be assigned to the sharded actor, where the current map breaks this pattern in terms of using Akka cluster sharding.

I'd appreciate any ideas.